# Magento - Migrate features from rwd to boilerplate theme

Tags: magento-1.9, boilerplate

I installed boilerplate from [GitHub](https://github.com/webcomm/magento-boilerplate) theme in my magento project, looks very good, some areas like my account and check section are very professional, but i prefer some little features from rwd project.

[image]

now i trying to get the right top section from rwd theme

[image]

and this is how i expect to see my new magento project

[image]

How shoud i change the right top (account and cart) from boilerplate theme without losing functionality?

Answer (score 1):

hmm .. You can create a new theme named for example : boiler-rwd-mixed.

The boiler-rwd-mixed theme integrating boilerplate functionnalities (block, layout, etc) and mixed with rwd style (css, layout, etc).

In boiler-rwd-mixed theme, the section to modify seems be in header or top.links area.

For your help you can enable the templates/blocks hints in admin panel.

In System > Configuration > Advanced > Developper > Debug :

- set Template Path Hints to Yes
- set Add Block Names to hints to Yes

  - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/frontend-dev-guide/themes/debug-theme.html